# How can I construct a scala.collection.immutable.List object in java

Tags: java, scala

I want to consturct an object of `scala.collection.immutable.List` type from my Java code. When I try to create it with `new` I get a error that says that `scala.collection.immutable.List` is abstract. What should I do instead?

Comment: Can you post the sample code that you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scala.collection.immutable.List` class is not very friendly to work from Java. Still you can use it from Java. Equivalent of Scala

```
val list = 3 :: 2 :: 1 :: Nil
```

would be something like

```
import scala.collection.immutable.List;
import scala.collection.immutable.Nil$;
import scala.collection.immutable.List$;
import scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon;

scala.collection.immutable.List<Integer> list = new $colon$colon(3, new $colon$colon(2, new $colon$colon(1, Nil$.MODULE$)));
```

Another and simpler in many cases way might be to construct Java collection first and only then convert it to Scala using `scala.collection.JavaConverters`. For example:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters;

java.util.List<Integer> javaList = new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();
javaList.add(3);
javaList.add(2);
javaList.add(1);
scala.collection.immutable.List<Integer> scalaList = JavaConverters.collectionAsScalaIterable(javaList).toList();
```

Comment: you are great!!

Answer (score 2):

Construct `List` using `List` companion object.

```
List(1, 2, 3)
```

Construct list using `::` operator.

```
val list = 1 :: 2 :: Nil
```

Refer scala docs for more info

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Comment: in java ,how to construct a scala List object?

Comment: @XiaolinWu Check this. http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~michelou/scala/using-scala-from-java.html